# How to subtract from previous row?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `np.array` stored in a variable, `x`, which looks like below:

```
array([[ 956],
       [ 929],
       [1083],
       [1074],
       [ 922]]
```

I want to subtract every number from the previous number, and I want a new variable, `y`, to look like below:

```
array([[ -27],
       [ 154],
       [  -9],
       [-152]]
```

Comment: look into `np.diff`

Comment: @PaulPanzer He's got a list of lists he has first to flatten.

Comment: @TonyTannous last time I checked diff had an `axis` parameter. Also, it's not a list of lists, it's a 2d array :-P

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([[ 956],
       [ 929],
       [1083],
       [1074],
       [ 922]] 

out = np.diff(out, axis=0)

Out: array([[ -27],
   [ 154],
   [  -9],
   [-152]]
```

Comment: Or `np.diff(a, axis=0)` (in this case, you don't need `hstack` and `L`)

Comment: When you use the `axis` parameter, you don't need to do `hstack` and the `L = ...` comprehension. Just `np.diff(x, axis=0)` and nothing else. See [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

Comment: @tobias_k, fixed. for a glance I thought it was a list of lists.... Not healthy to do multiple things.

Comment: out = np.diff(_out_, axis=0) what is the second `out`?

Comment: @3kstc
I simply overrode the out variable.
`np.diff` took two parameters, and the return values I stored in `out`.

Comment: @TonyTannous Thanks, I'm [stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998843/appending-to-a-new-column-the-differences-of-current-row-and-previous-row-for-m) with using the `diff`, any change you would you be able to help me out please?

Comment: @3kstc it is 02:20 am where I live and I need to wake up in 3 hours. I will take a look after I am back home (13~ hours from now).